# identify gender from the first name python

Tags: python, pandas

I have data set

first_name
ajay
amit
raj
mona
sema

and I want to identify the there gender from there first name with a new column Gender
so I used this code

```
!pip install gender_guesser
!pip install xlrd
!pip install openpyxl

import pandas as pd
import gender_guesser.detector as gender

df=pd.read_excel('adarsh.xlsx')

gd = gender.Detector()
df['Gender'] = df['first_name'].map(lambda x: gd.get_gender(x))
df['Gender']
```

output:
0       male

1    unknown

2    unknown

3    unknown

4    unknown

Name: Gender, dtype: object

how can get the complete output of gender

Comment: Does `gender_guesser` have support for Indian names?

Comment: You realise some names are used by both men and women (in the same culture or across cultures); some names will be sufficiently rare that the guesser can't; there aren't necessarily two (or some small number of) genders; and that some people will be deeply offended if you guess wrong, or that you're guessing at all?

Comment: About the only thing we can improve here is a trivial one: `.map(lambda x: gd.get_gender(x))` can be simplified to: `.map(gd.get_gender)`

Comment: now what should do??

Answer (score 1):

in general, gender_guesser.detector requires properly capitalized names.

thus, just add an additional step to capitalize the names before passing them into the guesser.

```
df['Gender'] = df['first_name'].apply(str.capitalize).map(lambda x: gd.get_gender(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

`unknown` implies that the package cannot identify the gender from the names you have inserted.

For the first name, the gender has been identified.

You should have a look into the names that have been catered for in the `gender-guesser` Python library.

Answer (score 0):

Possible error is due to Capitalization, because by default gender-guesser is case sensitive. Try setting it off and then search.
Check out the documentation https://pypi.org/project/gender-guesser/

```
>>> d = gender.Detector(case_sensitive=False)
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"sally"))
female
>>> print(d.get_gender(u"Sally"))
female
```